# Am trying to join three queries in an ACCESS but the result is duplicating

Tags: ms-access

why the result is duplicating for this query, am trying to combine three queries together in ACCESS

```
`SELECT qryNDI.tblNDI_First.Matric_no, qryNDI.tblNDI_First.TPoint, 
qryNDI.tblNDI_Second.TPoint, qryNDII.tblNDII_First.TPoint, 
qryNDII.tblNDII_Second.TPoint, qryNDIIYEARIII.tblNDIIYEARIII_First.TPoint, 
qryNDIIYEARIII.tblNDIIYEARIII_Second.TPoint FROM ((qryNDI INNER JOIN qryNDII 
ON qryNDI.tblNDI_First.Matric_no = qryNDII.Matric_no) INNER JOIN 
qryNDIIYEARIII ON qryNDII.Matric_no = qryNDIIYEARIII.Matric_no);`
```

Comment: It'd be hard to say the exact problem without knowing what data is being referenced. But, with joins, if there's more than one match in table_a, it's going to show each with duplicate table_b info.

Comment: the 'possible' reason is, you have your first table to second table, if there is more than one match in second table you will see the first duplicated.  this is exactly what @'John Ink' stated

Answer (score 1):

possible quick fix!  use 'distinct' right after 'select'.  [Distinct Description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177882(v=office.12).aspx)

```
SELECT distinct qryNDI.tblNDI_First.Matric_no, qryNDI.tblNDI_First.TPoint, 
qryNDI.tblNDI_Second.TPoint, qryNDII.tblNDII_First.TPoint, 
qryNDII.tblNDII_Second.TPoint, qryNDIIYEARIII.tblNDIIYEARIII_First.TPoint, 
qryNDIIYEARIII.tblNDIIYEARIII_Second.TPoint FROM ((qryNDI INNER JOIN qryNDII 
ON qryNDI.tblNDI_First.Matric_no = qryNDII.Matric_no) INNER JOIN 
qryNDIIYEARIII ON qryNDII.Matric_no = qryNDIIYEARIII.Matric_no);
```

to help understand the relationship between the data.  example: you have one parent table row that matches three child table rows then your query will show three rows, only if those three child rows are unique in some way. if they differ only by the identifier using distinct may give you the results your looking for.

I cannot 'comment' because my rep points aren't high enough.